# Pass awk variable to command and read output

Tags: awk

I would like to sort file in parts delimeted by string, but it is a larger part of processing in the awk.

I have read that it could be possible to store lines between delimeter and then use asort for sorting, but I need to sort it using the second column.

I have decided to store output between delimeter in a variable (*k*), then pass the value of variable into command using pipe *|*, and, at the end read the output, process it and print.

However, using the `print variable|"sort -k2,2"|getline v` makes the *getline*(?) to stuck.

I can execute command in *uglier* way using `system()` function, but then I think that I need to use echo to pass variable to command, and the output is not stored in variable v, but the error code.

```bsh
$ awk 'BEGIN{ cmd="sort -k2,2"; k="1\tB\n2\tA"; v=system("echo \""k"\" | "cmd); print "OK: "v}'
2       A
1       B
OK: 0
```

The *nicer* way with `print k|command` (removing `|getline v`) executes command, but the `print "OK"` is done before output from subcommand. The output is also not stored in variable *v*.

```bsh
$ awk 'BEGIN{ cmd="sort -k2,2"; k="1\tB\n2\tA"; print k|cmd; print "OK: "v}'
OK:
2       A
1       B
```

How can I store command output in variable or at least to wait for the previous subcommand to finish before continuing?

Comment: what specifc thing you want to do that you use awk? Cannot you use just `sort -k2,2 inputfile` directly? because nothing you validate for the command result or anything in awk. what is your input and expected output? can you [edit] and show these instead?

Comment: ... the piece you're missing is probably a `close(cmd)` statement to prevent `sort` from waiting for more input. See for example [close() function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#index-close_0028_0029-function)

Comment: @αғsнιη the awk is processing output from the other command (namely `squeue`), and I don't need full information about the other users' jobs, and I want to _collapse_ them, but I still need to leave my submitted jobs in right place to know, when they will be eligible for the run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to do (using GNU awk for [coprocesses](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Two_002dway-I_002fO))?

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    cmd = "sort -k2,2"
    k = "1\tB\n2\tA"

    print k |& cmd
    close(cmd, "to")

    while ((cmd |& getline line) > 0) {
        v = v line ORS
    }
    close(cmd)

    print "OK:"
    printf "%s", v
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk
OK:
2       A
1       B
```

Since the above uses GNU awk (and you already mentioned [asort()](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Array-Sorting-Functions) in your question which is gawk-only) and gawk already has sorting built in, you probably don't need to do that anyway, e.g. using [sorted_in](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Controlling-Array-Traversal) instead of creating a subshell for every call to `sort` as the above would do:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    k = "1\tB\n2\tA"

    split(k,lines,/\n/)
    for (i in lines) {
        lines[i] = gensub(/[^\t]*\t([^\t]+)/,"\\1\t&",1,lines[i])
    }

    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_str_asc"
    for (i in lines) {
        v = v gensub(/[^\t]\t/,"",1,lines[i]) ORS
    }

    print "OK:"
    printf "%s", v
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk
OK:
2       A
1       B
```

but I assume this is a simplified version of some more difficult task you're trying to perform that actually would require coprocesses.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone interested in the solution of the problem described in the [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/634976/pass-awk-variable-to-command-and-read-output#comment1189409_634976):

> the awk is processing output from the other command (namely squeue), and I don't need full information about the other users' jobs, and I want to collapse them, but I still need to leave my submitted jobs in right place to know, when they will be eligible for the run.

```bsh
alias squeue="_squeue() {
    /usr/bin/squeue --format=\"%.8i %.9P %.20j %.10u %.2t %.10M %.10L %.6D %R\" \$@ \
    | awk '
        BEGIN { cmd=\"sort -k2,2 -k5,5 -k4,4\" }
        function sort(buf) {
            sorted=\"\"
            gsub(\"^\"ORS\"*|\"ORS\"{2,}|\"ORS\"*$\", \"\", buf)
            if (length(buf)>0) {
                print buf |& cmd
                close(cmd, \"to\")
                while ((cmd |& getline line) > 0) {
                    sorted = sorted line ORS
                }
                close(cmd)
            }
            return sorted
          }
          NR <= 1 { print; next }
          /'\$USER'/ {
              printf(\"%s\", sort(buf))
              buf=\"\"
              print
              partition=\$2; user=\$4; st=\$5;
              next
          }
          { buf = buf ORS \$0 }
          END {
              printf(\"%s\", sort(buf))
          }
        ' \
    | awk '
        BEGIN { partition=\"\"; user=\"\"; st=\"\"; c=0; n=0; }
        function print_count() {
            if(c>0) { print \" (count: \"c\" jobs, \"n\" nodes)\"; c=0; n=0; }
        }
        NR <= 1 { print \$0; next }
        /'\$USER'/ {
            print_count()
            print;
            next
        }
        \$2!=partition || \$4!=user || \$5!=st {
            print_count()
            printf(\"%-98s\", substr(\$0,0, 98));
            partition=\$2; user=\$4; st=\$5;
        }
        { n+=\$8; c++ }
        END {
            print_count()
        }' \
    |  sed '/(count: .*)$/{s/.*/\x1b[90m&\x1b[0m/p;d};
            /\s'\$USER'\s\+[^R]\+\s/{s/.*/\x1b[1m&\x1b[0m/p;d}'
}
_squeue"
```